# "Your First Meteor Application": Form won't log to console (link to code on MeteorPad included)

Tags: meteor

Going through *Your First Meteor Application* and I'm stuck. I'm in [Chapter 9 "Forms"](http://meteortips.com/book/forms/) at the section titled "The Event Object, Part 1."

I can't get anything to log to the console.

Here's where I'm at via MeteorPad:

[Source code](http://meteorpad.com/pad/ryrg5Str7K5Mo5LKz/MeteorTips.ch9(Forms).form%20won't%20work) (I've made a comment saying "THIS IS WHERE I'M STUCK" on line 46 of common.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `<form>` tag.

This is how the insert event should look.

```
 Template.addPlayerForm.events({
    'submit form': function(event,template){
      event.preventDefault();
      PlayersList.insert({
        name:template.$('#newPlayer').val(),
        score:8,
        })
      return false;
    }
  });
```

And the **HTML**.

```
<template name="addPlayerForm">
 <form>
    <input type="text" name="playerName" id="newPlayer">
    <input type="submit" value="Add Player">
 </form>
</template>
```

Here is the same [meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/C3e6qzLkoynpqcS8Y/Copy%20of%20MeteorTips.ch9(Forms).form%20won't%20work) but with the above changes.